# Remove the menu from insertdatetime splitbutton

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins

I've added an insertdatetime button to my toolbar, which has an icon + a drop-down menu.

I've removed all the menu options, because I only want a single-click button, that inserts current date/time.

Is it possible to remove the drop-down (menu) part of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible out of the box, as the default button in the Insert Date/Time plugin will always use a split toolbar button. If you want just a regular toolbar button you'd need to create a custom button. Here's an example to show how this can be done by making use of the `mceInsertDate` command provided by the Insert Date/Time plugin: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/9Phaab

```
editor.ui.registry.addButton('insertdate', {
  icon: 'insert-time',
  tooltip: 'Insert date',
  onAction: () => editor.execCommand('mceInsertDate')
});
```

More information can be found in the TinyMCE documentation:

- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/insertdatetime/
- https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/ui-components/typesoftoolbarbuttons/#basicbutton

Comment: Many thanks for your reply newso.  I was hoping there'd be a simple 'button-menu: false' or some such, but I shall work it out from the links you provided.